# Como interactuar con la base de datos MYSQL de otra PC en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

ahora estoy tratando de conectarme a una base de datos que se encuentra en otra PC, ambos estamos en la misma red, lo que pasa es que esta otra PC presenta una tabla actualizada de datos que diariamente es modificada, entonces yo necesito hacer las consultas alli. ambos estamos en la misma red(el mio 172.xx.xx.ab y el de la otra PC es 172.xx.xx.aa) y la base de datos que el presenta se llama "mantenimiento" y la tabla "direccion", habra alguna manera de llamar la base de datos a de otra PC en un codigo de PHP ?

he hecho una manera de consultar, osea asi:

```
 <?php 
  //Opciones de la conexión 
  $opciones = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"); 
  //Objeto PDO, Controlador de BD, IP del servidor o localhost, nombre de la BD, usuario y contraseña 
  $objetoPDO = new PDO('mysql:host=172.xx.xx.ab;dbname=mantenimiento','root','',$opciones); ?>
```

y el error me sale de la siguiente manera:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '(hostanme)' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server' in C:\xampp\htdocs\j7\ejemplo.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\j7\ejemplo.php(4): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=172...', 'root', '', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\j7\ejemplo.php on line 4
```

Comment: pues con PDO o mysql haciendo la conexión y en vez de poner localhost en la variable server puedes colocar la IP

Comment: el codigo seria de la siguiente manera                                               
  <?php
  //Opciones de la conexión
  $opciones = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8");
  //Objeto PDO, Controlador de BD, IP del servidor o localhost, nombre de la BD, usuario y contraseña
  $objetoPDO = new PDO('mysql:host=172.xx.xx.ab;dbname=mantenimiento','root','',$opciones);
?>

Comment: ya lo intentaste? que fallos te ha dado?

Comment: sale que no puedo conectarme al servidor de la otra PC

Comment: dale en editar a tu pregunta y añade lo que haz tratado incluido el código usado y el error tal cual aparece

Comment: ya modifique mi pregunta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83401/discussion-between-kevincs7-and-alfredo-paz).